# ffmpeg concat error unable to find a suitable output format

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to batch concat a outro video to multiple videos. 
I am just tetsing it using the following command:
`ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i hello.mp4 -filter comp
lex “[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]” -map “[v]” -map “[a]” outpu
t_video.mp4`

> However I get the following Error:

`[NULL @ 04fc2c00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]'
[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]: Invalid argument`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard any suggestions as to how i can use this code or `ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4` method to add outro to 100's of videos?

Comment: yes i upvoted. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Change `-filter complex` to `-filter_complex`
2. Replace the “smart / fancy” quotes with normal double quotes (`"`).